# How to handle shots with Picamera2?

Tags: camera, raspicam, picamera, libcamera

I'm looking for code to handle shots with Picamera2.
I want:

- Take photo with the camera
- Show plan on screen for x seconds
- Save photo as jpeg image.

I try the code below but can't find how to adjust the image preview display time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
i = 0

picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
preview_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
capture_config = picam2.create_still_configuration()

picam2.configure(preview_config)
picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    i = i + 1
    file_name = "photo" + str(i) + ".jpg"

    picam2.switch_mode_and_capture_image(capture_config)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

On page 12 of the [PiCamera2 manual](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf):

```
picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)
picam2.stop_preview()
```